# How to access an element of a nested list with loop

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

how to access an element of nested list with a loop? like:

```py
a = [20,[22,[3,[21],3], 30]]
               #^^ i want to access this
```

how to access it with a loop, insead of using

```py
a[1][1][1][1]
```

any solution on any language is accepted (preferably python)

Comment: Are you trying to iterate to see all of the items in the nested list, or just a specific item?

Comment: @Axiumin_ just one specific item

Comment: Do you want this to be dynamic or will the lists of lists be one element each?

Comment: @12944qwerty i want this to be dynamic

Comment: I think recursion is the best way (instead of a loop). See SomeDude's answer down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not via an explicit loop, but you can use the [`functoools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function as illustrated below:

```
from functools import reduce

def nested_getter(lst, *args):
    return reduce(lambda s, i: s[i], args, lst)


a = [20,[22,[3,[21]]]]
print(nested_getter(a, 1, 1, 1, 0))  # -> 21
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like:

```
def get_inner_most(a):
  if not isinstance(a, list):
    return a
  elif len(a) == 0:
    return None
  elif len(a) == 1:
    return a[0]
  return get_inner_most(a[1])
```

You need to note that it will get you only the first inner most element found and I hope that is your requirement.
For example for the input `[20,[22,[3,[21],3], 30], [9,[4,[5,[6]]]]]` it will still return `21` but not `6`. If that is your requirement i.e. the element at the largest depth then you need to update  your question.